# How can we omit approve function?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Now I'm building ink! smartcontract based AMM, as you know there are needed to approve before adding liquidity in general. but it's bad UX for users cuz we need to approve several times before adding liquidity or swapping.

Uniswap and other EVM based AMM were overcoming this issue as you know EIP-2612.

Permit function is implemented in ERC20, are there any kinds of the function like this in PSP22??

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2612

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20Permit

Answer (score 2):

`permit` function from EIP-2612 is really Ethereum-centric but you can still adapt it ink! & substrate. 
But you need to restrict your contract to only be used by ECDSA addresses.
Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9609)

And the [implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/9686) of `seal_ecdsa_recovery` in pallet_contract

And the code snippet in top of `ecdsa_recover` in [ink! repo](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/beccff6409100e30a37144d4acfff2ac83b7bf29/crates/ink/src/env_access.rs#L724)

Comment: Thank you.
I have checked the issue but it doesn't make me clear...
This is why ??
`But you need to restrict your contract to only be used by ECDSA addresses.`

Comment: explained there :https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3220/567