# Does polkadot.js extension expose a method for signing using ECDSA?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension, ecdsa

So far it looks like `polkadot.js/api` supports ECDSA signatures, but the polkadot.js extension doesn't expose a method to use ECDSA:

- [How to sign a message using ECDSA key pairs in Polkadot.js so it can be verified in the ink! contract](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3213/how-to-sign-a-message-using-ecdsa-key-pairs-in-polkadot-js-so-it-can-be-verified)
- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/extension/cookbook#sign-a-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be so, however there's a [tracking bug for it](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/issues/1237). The [moonbase docs](https://docs.moonbeam.network/tokens/connect/polkadotjs/) recommend using the in-browser local storage. If you try to submit the extrinsic with an ecdsa signature using the extension over the moonbase network (which is using ecdsa as a signature method), then it will fail with a mismatch of types.